# Access to Kubernetes service non-HA or HA cluster

Tags: kubernetes, cluster, high-availability

My setup has previously been one control node (non-HA) and a few worker nodes on Kubernetes. New I'm building up a new cluster with three control nodes (HA) and 9 worker nodes. Connection from browser is made with secured websocket (wss).

Non-HA setup is working with external address of wss://api.xxxx.com without problems. Now when HA-cluster is set up, I cannot connect anymore to address wss://api.xxxx.com, just getting message to browser `NS_ERROR_GENERATE_FAILURE(NS_ERROR_MODULE_SECURITY,SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG)`. Kubernetes cluster certificates are ok for domain api.xxxx.com.

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that there is a problem with the security certificate & server side issue used by your Kubernetes cluster. Here are a few possible causes and solutions:

1. Check Firewall rules,Antivirus Software, load balancers, and network policies in place.
2. Ensure that the certificates are valid, signed by a trusted Certificate Authority (CA),  and include the correct domain name ([api.xxxx.com](http://api.xxxx.com)).
3. Check the DNS configuration to confirm that the hostname [api.xxxx.com](http://api.xxxx.com) resolves to the correct IP address of the HA-cluster. Ensure proper DNS record
4. Ensure that port 443 is used for secure connections on your website and properly configured and open your server.
5. Verify that no more than one SSL certificate is using the same IP address. Please make sure that each SSL certificate has a distinct IP address. Check SSL certificate is valid (Check the expiration date of the certificate and renew it if necessary). Also see this open github [issue](https://github.com/browsh-org/browsh/issues/127).
6. In rare cases, this problem may be resolved by cleaning or avoiding the cache.Try with different browsers Using an Incognito or Private Window to see the website without using cookies or cache is the simplest approach to test this.
7. Consider upgrading TLS Version support and browser version also helps  to fix this error

Refer to this [blog](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/ssl_error_rx_record_too_long/#:%7E:text=In%20a%20nutshell%2C%20the%20most,have%20a%20misconfigured%20listing%20port) by Kinsta for more information

**EDIT:1**

8. Check all hosts in the cluster must have access to the same shared storage. In any case of failure, a virtual machine (VM) on one host can failover to another host, without any downtime.
9. The best way to “upgrade” a non-HA control plane to an HA control plane is to build a new HA control plane and migrate all your workloads.
10. To fix your issue you may need to update the certificate so that the list of SANs includes any and all IP addresses or hostnames that you will use to access the API server Update Control Plane Components.

As per this [blog](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2019/08/12/converting-kubernetes-to-ha-control-plane/) by Scott's Weblog you may also need to update control plane components.

> “Just as you updated the Kubeconfig file (by modifying the server:
> line for the cluster being modified to point to the load balancer)
> used by the Kubelet, you’ll also need to update the Kubeconfig files
> that the controller manager and scheduler use to connect to the API
> server.
>
> **The files that need to be modified are:**
>
> ```
> /etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
> /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
> ```
>
> These files are standard Kubeconfig files. The only line that needs to
> be changed is the server: line that specifies the API endpoint (this
> is currently probably pointing to the IP address or hostname of the
> single control plane node). Edit each of these files to point to an IP
> address or DNS name for the load balancer (and for which a SAN exists
> on the API server certificate). For these components to pick up the
> change, you’ll need to restart them.”

Also see this [doc](https://docs.microfocus.com/NNMi/10.30/Content/Administer/NNMi_Deployment/Resilience/Common_Configuration_Mis.htm) by Micro focus on  Common High Availability Configuration Mistakes

Comment: Thank's!  All seems to be ok and clear, but point 3.: 
any idea, what address should be use with HA-cluster?  Now it is the same as before. Should it be something else?

Comment: Could you verify the cluster configurations to make sure the hostname api.xxxx.com is set up to use the correct IP address and is connected to the HA cluster? Use a DNS resolution tool such as dig or nslookup to verify the [DNS resolution](https://docs.cleartax.in/cleartax-docs/general/how-to-check-dns-resolution)

Comment: When an HA cluster is configured, you can display the IP addresses that are used in the HA cluster. However your curser over the **Host Name field** on the System and License Management window. for more information see this [doc](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/qsip/7.5?topic=management-creating-ha-cluster)

Comment: Resolving address from dns-name seems to be ok, no difference between tools. I just use command line on Linux :-)

Comment: Yes you are right @ajlind

Comment: yeps, always, when somehow solved. This is still totally open

Comment: Just updated my answer. Have a look at the **EDIT1** section and also see this similar [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65505137/how-to-convert-a-kubernetes-non-ha-control-plane-into-an-ha-control-plane), Which may help to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution or actually my misconfiguration. There where misspelled name on haproxy/ingress certificates yaml-file. So there is nothing to do with kubernetes. I can accept Sai's answer, how I found it